# Как правильно использовать Promise для полной синхронности?

Tags: javascript, promise

Есть функция

```
function func() {
    getData().then(result => {
      // Код
    });
  }

  return [
    {
      // код
    },
  ];
}
```

Из нее мы вызываем метод, который делает запрос и возвращает промис.

```
async function getDataRequst() {
  const response = await getData(); // getData это запрос, который возвращает промис.

  return response;
}

function getData() {
  return new Promise<any>(resolve => {
        const data = await getDataRequest();
        resolve(data);
      }
}
```

Должно работать оно так:
1. Мы вызываем метод func, у нас выполняется промис, который находится в getData, далее с ним что-то происходит в then'e и только потом срабатывает return.
Сейчас return срабатывает ровно в тот момент, когда вызывается метод getData, не дождавшись, пока выполнится промис.
Очень мало работал с промисами, и не могу понять, в чем дело.

Comment: здесь не нужна обертка promise, можно убрать полностью `getData` и использовать `getDataRequst`

Comment: `async function getDataRequst() {` и `await getDataRequest();` тут должна была быть одна и та же функция???

Answer (score 0):

```
function func(){
    return [
        {
          // код
        },
    ];
}

getData()
.then(result => {
// Код
})
.then(func)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]